# How can I execute a .py file in another one and pass a list to it as its input?

Tags: python, list

I am going to send a list as an input to a `.py` file which should be executed in my `main.py` ; I tried following code but it returns `None`:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr1 = exec(open("G:/My Drive/Python Project/Algorithm1.py").read())
print(arr1)
```

Algorithm1 file also contains this code:

```
def pr_array(array):
    array2 = []
    for i in array:
        array2.append(i) 
    return array2

pr_array(arr)
```

Note: I have a lot of files that I'm going to execute in the main file, and each of them has multiple functions; if I want to import them one by one, that would be too many, so this solution does not work.

Comment: Why not import `pr_array` to `main.py` and then call `pr_array` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can import functions from another file in the `main.py`.

`Algorithm1.py`

```
def pr_array(array):
    array2 = []
    for i in array:
        array2.append(i) 
    return array2
```

`main.py`

```
from Algorithm1 import pr_array
arr = [1,2,3]
arr1 = pr_array(arr)
print(arr1)
```

Comment: Thank you but actually, I have lots of `.py`  files containing more than one function; that's why I'm getting file name and running the related file.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question a bit more?

Comment: I have a lot of files that I'm going to execute in the main file, and each of them has multiple functions; if I want to import them one by one, that would be too many.

Comment: So I decided to get the file name and execute it at once.